# Clear data present in files folder of the app

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

In my app, I am downloading some files. It gets automatically saved in `data/data/project/files` folder. Below code is used for that purpose.

```
URL url = new URL(audioUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();  
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int j;
while((j = inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, j);
}
fos.close();
```

What I require is: before adding anything to this folder i want to clear all files if any are present. How can I do that? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by giving:

```
String[] allFiles = fileList();
for(int k = 0 ; k < allFiles.length; k++) {
    deleteFile(allFiles[k]);
}
```